# Find out message size - maximum limit set on the server

Tags: outlook

I am trying to send a message with an attachment of size 40mb. I get error message "the message size exceeds the maximum limit set on the server". How to find out the maximum limit set on the server myself before asking the IT engineer? I am simple end user who can login and check/send mails without any admin privileges on the outlook server. I use outlook client 2011 and I don't know the version of the outlook server.

Answer (score 0):

Read the PR_MAX_SUBMIT_MESSAGE_SIZE MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x666D0003`) using Store.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty.